# Can you pass a "next" back to the function that called the current function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, foreach, each

I have a series of nested `each` loops that iterate through a list of cards. These loops call out to other sub-functions that test if certain conditions are met in order to proceed.

```
def card_handler
    cards.each do |card|

      #some non-relevant code is here on my end

      already_sent?
    end
  end


  def already_sent?
    # allows for checking if different emails have been sent on the same card

    if list_action == 147
      a_s_helper(p1_label)
    elsif list_action == 146
      a_s_helper(p2_label)
    elsif list_action == 145
      a_s_helper(p3_label)
    end
  end

  def a_s_helper(label)

    if card::card_labels.include? label
    # if the card already has the label, I want to log the error and return all the way to the next card in the iteration

    puts '\n Order info: \n id: #{id} \n Email already sent'

    next 
    # doesn't work


    else
      real_id?
    end
  end
```

Like I say in my comment in a_s_helper, if the card already has the label, I want to log the error and return all the way to the next card in the iteration. I get an "Invalid next" error from the current setup.

Is there a way to return a `next` back to the parent function or loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`next` is only valid in the direct context of a loop. Once you call into a method, you are no longer directly in that loop context. You cannot use next to short-circuit the outer loop like this.

You have a couple of options:

1. Return statuses from your predicate functions (which is what you should do, from a predicate!) and short-circuit the loop based on those, or
2. Use Ruby's `catch...throw` construct (which is NOT its raise/rescue exception handler, but is instead [something like a block-scoped GOTO statement](http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/tut_exceptions.html))

Option 1: Returning statuses. This is the most appropriate method, IMO. Predicate methods (those ending in ?) should conventionally return a boolean and be idempotent (that is, should have no side effects, such as logging a statement). They are conventionally used to ask a yes/no question. Deciding what to do based on that question should ideally be outside of their scope.

```rb
def card_handler
  cards.each do |card|
    #some non-relevant code is here on my end
    if already_sent?
      puts '\n Order info: \n id: #{id} \n Email already sent'
      next
    end
  end
end


def already_sent?
  case list_action
  when 145
    a_s_helper(p3_label)
  when 145
    a_s_helper(p2_label)
  when 147
    a_s_helper(p1_label)
  end
end

def a_s_helper(label)
  card::card_labels.include? label
end
```

This causes your helpers to return a true or false value to your loop, which can decide to log a message and go to the next iteration.

Option 2: `catch...throw`

```rb
def card_handler
  cards.each do |card|
    # Put all your code that should nomally run inside the catch block. If
    # the message :email_sent is thrown, then Ruby will zip up the stack and
    # resume execution at the end of the block. This will skip any unexecuted
    # code in the block, essentially terminating the execution.
    catch :email_sent do
      already_sent?
    end
  end
end


def already_sent?
  # ...
end

def a_s_helper(label)
  # ... 
  throw :email_sent if card::card_labels.include? label
  # ... 
end
```

You may be tempted to use option 2, since it requires less careful control over method construction, but it is perilously close to [exceptions as flow control](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why) which are widely considered an antipattern (it's essentially a slightly more fancy GOTO, which is notorious for making code difficult to read and debug). If you can simply return a status from your helpers and decide whether or not to continue the loop based on that, you should do so.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using the first method. I should have realized that would work. I'm relatively new to ruby and oop in general. Thanks for pointing out the best practices as well.

Answer (score 0):

I want to show how I ended up implementing the solution I got from @Chris-heald for future people who see this question. I made it a little more compact. This was the code I ended up using:

```
  def card_handler
    cards.each do |card|
      real_id?
      puts "real_id? : #{real_id?}"
      next if !(real_id?)

      needs_email?
      puts "needs_email? : #{needs_email?}"
      next if !(needs_email?)

      get_email_info
    end
  end


  def needs_email?
    case list_action
    when 147
      !(card::card_labels.include? p1_label::id)
    when 146
      !(card::card_labels.include? p2_label::id)
    when 145
      !(card::card_labels.include? p3_label::id)
    else
      false
    end
  end

  def real_id?
    id != 0 ? true : false
  end

  def get_email_info
    #more stuff
  end
```